# Do flowfields Value Change if Filters are applied to the Table?

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, navision

I have a flowfield that sums up a decimal value, but I need to limit the value in a report based on a date field that will be supplied as a parameter in a 
report. How best do I achieve this? 
 a shortened version the CALC formula in the field definition looks like this:

```
Sum("MyTable".Unit WHERE (Institution=FIELD(No)))
```

When the report is run, there is a filter on MyTable based on a date field.
Does this field evaluate to the total sum of all the records, or just the filtered values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Just filter on any field doesn't applies to flow fields.

You must use [flowfilter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd354997(v=nav.71).aspx) to achieve this.

Your code should look like this:

```
MytableVar.reset;
MytableVar.setrange("Date Filter", 0D, TODAY);
MytableVar.calcfields(Unit);
```

where `Date Filter` is a field in the `My Table` with type `flowfilter`.

If `My Table` is used as Source Table it will work in tha same way. Just apply filter to `Date Filter` field.

For further reference see `Inventory` filed  in the `Item` table.